# Ошибка при рассчете количества записей с помощью запроса SQLQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Написал запрос

```
Select (Hostel.RoomsCount - Count(Rooms.RoomId)) AS FreeRooms

From Rooms inner join Hostel ON (Hostel.HostelCode=Rooms.HostelCode)

WHERE Hostel.HostelCode= 1
```

Выводит ошибку

```
Column 'Hostel.HostelCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select (Hostel.RoomsCount - Count(Rooms.RoomId)) AS FreeRooms

From Rooms inner join Hostel ON (Hostel.HostelCode=Rooms.HostelCode)

WHERE Hostel.HostelCode= 1

GROUP BY Hostel.RoomsCount
```